# Dockerfile CMD `command not found`

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nodesource/node:jessie

ADD ./ /SOMEPATH

RUN cd /SOMEPATH && npm install

WORKDIR /SOMEPATH

CMD [“bash”, “npm run lint”]
```

When I build and run this image using this command:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/SOMEPATH Name_of_image
```

I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: [“bash”,: not found
```

However, when I run the image like this, it works:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/SOMEPATH Name_of_image NAME_OF_TASK
```

So, why does this work? And why doesn't the other one work?

Comment: what´s NAME_OF_TASK in your example?

Comment: @christian `gulp` in that example basically whatever is in CMD ['x'] it cannot find that command

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are using wrong quotes. It should be:

```
CMD ["bash", "npm run lint"]
```

Comment: This is super bizaro