# Binaries inside Docker container images not being started when not explicitly called

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

I'm building my own Dockerfile with official images as it's base which I'm adjusting with Ansible for simple configuration changes. Relevant portion of the dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm
MAINTAINER hyperfocus

# Ansible cmds

EXPOSE 9000
CMD [“php-fpm”]
```

Whenever the image is built and I try to start it with `docker run php_fpm_prod:v0.1` it gives me the error: `/bin/sh: 1: [“php-fpm”]: not found`.

But whenever I try to start it with `docker run php_fpm_prod:v0.1 php-fpm` it starts succesfully:

```
[03-Nov-2015 10:24:38] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
[03-Nov-2015 10:24:38] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

How can I make `docker run php_fpm_prod:v0.1` behave like `docker run php_fpm_prod:v0.1 php-fpm`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CMD` of a [php fpm Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/8a828032adbeab081ed1de9a3e42f11981b0541b/7.0/fpm/Dockerfile#L60) is already `CMD ["php-fpm"]` (overriding the [debian-jessie `CMD`](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-debian/blob/a9fff0a31ade29befe4a8627f5829e4c592ba306/jessie/Dockerfile#L3)), so you shouldn't need to specify it again.

Those debian or php fpm Dockerfile don't define an [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime) which means thedefault one applies `/bin/sh -c`.

First, make sure, as in "[Dockerfile `CMD` `command not found`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30651455/6309)" to use the right quotes:

```
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

(Or don't specify the `CMD` at all, since it will be inherited from the base image)

Comment: @Hyperfocus if you do specify a `CMD`, make sure to use `"`, not curly `“` (http://typographyforlawyers.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html)