# Dockerfile and Rails Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerfile

I'm following a tutorial to test out Docker with a Rails application.  The URL is: https://blog.codeship.com/running-rails-development-environment-docker/

I have native Docker installed on my Mac and I'm working on step 2.  The Dockerfile is listed below.  Everything compiles fine for:

```
docker build -t demo .
docker run -it demo "bundle exec rake test"
```

But when I run `docker run -itP demo` to start the application I get an error:

```
/bin/sh:1: ["bundle",: not found
```

I cannot find a reference to this error anywhere.  What do I need to do to resolve this issue?

```
FROM ruby:2.2 
MAINTAINER marko@codeship.com

# Install apt based dependencies required to run Rails as 
# well as RubyGems. As the Ruby image itself is based on a 
# Debian image, we use apt-get to install those.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ 
   build-essential \ 
   nodejs

# Configure the main working directory. This is the base 
# directory used in any further RUN, COPY, and ENTRYPOINT 
# commands.
RUN mkdir -p /app 
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Gemfile as well as the Gemfile.lock and install 
# the RubyGems. This is a separate step so the dependencies 
# will be cached unless changes to one of those two files 
# are made.
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./ 
RUN gem install bundler && bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5

# Copy the main application.
COPY . ./

# Expose port 3000 to the Docker host, so we can access it 
# from the outside.
EXPOSE 3000

# The main command to run when the container starts. Also 
# tell the Rails dev server to bind to all interfaces by 
# default.
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: Did you check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651045/dockerfile-cmd-command-not-found ?

Comment: You are exactly right!  I'm newer to Macs and I was using the built in document editor to get started prior to downloading a code editor such as Atom.  The difference in parentheses was causing my error.